# Shared calendar in company with Mac and Windows computers

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook, calendar, icloud, icalendar

I would like to give my company a common ground to work on in aspects of a calendars where everybody notes his "dates" / meetings.

Some of my employees work with Mac, and some work with Windows.

I would like to see the dates / meetings that my people have noted.

I would like to ask if this is possible using iCloud and the Mac calendar and Outlook with an add-in.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I use a Mac as well, and have to use Outlook for work. I have my work email set up on my phone, which sends mail as well as any events/meetings that I have scheduled from my Outlook calendar that show in my calendar on my iPhone. As far as vice versa, working with Windows, I have no idea. Sorry!